# Why is number of votes in a day a factor in determining the point per vote

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading a book and having difficulty understanding some simple division.

In the book we are building a scoring system for articles and voting.

It says, we are listing articles with at least 200 votes in a single day in the top 50 articles. So, for one day, thats 86400 seconds, and then they divide by 200 being the minimum number of votes in a day required for posting on top 50, which comes to 432 points per vote. Why would the factor of number of votes in a day provide an outcome of points per vote? Its been a long time since ive used math and im just not sure why the factor of minimum required votes is a determining factor in the point per vote.

From Book:

When dealing with scores that go down over time, we need to make the posting time, the current time, or both relevant to the overall score. To keep things simple, we'll say that the score of an item is a function of the time that the article was posted, plus a constant multiplier times the number of votes that the article has received

The time well use the number of seconds since January 1,1970, in the UTC time zone, which is commonly referred to as Unix time. For our constant, we'll take the number of seconds in a day (86400) divided by the number of votes required (200) to last a full day, which gives us 432 "points" added to the score per vote.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Can you give a bit more context or perhaps even a direct quote from the text? It's difficult to understand based on just your explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 done

Comment: Let's break down the phrase... "Points Per Vote."  When we use the word "per" that implies we are talking about a ratio.  "Points Per Vote" to me then sounds like $\dfrac{\text{number of points total}}{\text{number of votes total}}$.  Why did we divide?  Because that is what "per" essentially means.

Comment: The ratio that it appears you actually calculated, $\frac{86400~\text{seconds}}{200~\text{votes}}$ is $432$ *Seconds Per Vote*.  That is to say, if an article gets at least one vote for every 432 seconds on average, then it will have at least 200 votes total over the day.

Comment: @JMoravitz Perfect explanation thanks. Maybe make it an answer so you can get credit.